# Eagerloading files in directories inside the app folder in Rails 3. How is it done?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I read this:

> If you add a dir directly under app/
>
> Do nothing. All files in this dir are eager loaded in production and
>   lazy loaded in development by default.
>
> **If you add a dir under app/something/**
>
> (e.g. app/models/concerns/, app/models/products/)
>
> Ask: do I want to namespace modules and classes inside my new dir? For
>   example in app/models/products/ you would need to wrap your class in
>   module Products.
>
> If the answer is yes, do nothing. It will just work.
>
> If the answer is no, add config.autoload_paths += %W(
>   #{config.root}/app/models/products )

I want to know how Rails does this. How does it:

1. Load the file inside a folder (named folder_nest) in the app folder only if the contents of that file are wrapped in a module named after that folder (folder_nest module). How does this happen?

There must be some logic that says: "if the thing inside of app is a file, eager load it. If it's a folder, only load the contents of said folder if it's wrapped in a module named after said folder."

Anyone know where this logic is? How do I read Rails source code?

Also, is config/initializers eagerly loaded? Where is that logic?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you have a lot of questions best answered by the one question "How do I read Rails source code"

Personally, I do something like the following from the command-line:

```
subl `bundle show rails`
```

and then use the text editor (sublime in this case, textmate also works) + search, just read the code. Sometimes I'll insert "puts" statements in there to make sure I'm reading the right code and run it just to be sure.

You can answer most of your own questions about the initialization sequence, etc, that way.